# Do XML processors apply <?xml-stylesheet PIs by default?

Tags: html, xml, wsdl, xslt-1.0

I just wrote an XSL-T file that converts some WSDL files into HTML documentation. Now I'm wondering whether I could use an processing-instruction like the following directly in the WSDL files:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="./transform.xsl"?>
```

This works perfectly in any browser I've tested. But I'm curious whether XML processors that actually want to use the WSDL as service description (e.g. SOAP client libraries) would now also convert the document into HTML - which would lead to an unusable WSDL.

Does anyone know whether this is safe or if there's some standard for XML processors that defines how to handle the xml-stylesheet processing instruction?